# trying to copy textarea into iframe

Tags: php, iframe

Hello so i have a textrea and i want when a user inserts data it will be displayed in the iframe i have come so far for now the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["preveri"]))
    {
    $koda = $_POST["koda"];
    $fp = fopen('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tutorial\koda.php');
    fwrite($fp, '$koda');
    fclose($fp);
    }
?>
<body>
    <table style="width: 841px; height: 511px">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <form method="post" action="tutorial.php">
                <textarea name="koda" cols="50" rows="30"></textarea>
                <p><input name="preveri" type="submit" value="Preveri" /></p>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <iframe src="koda.php" width="450px" height="470px"></iframe>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It looks like some kind of preview... What is advantage of this instead of display it into some div? If there will be some modification required (like BBCode > HTML), AJAX can help.

Comment: its gonna be for html code so if a user inserst a html code it will get displayed how it will look

Comment: Well, if you put HTML from textarea into div, it will be interpreted too.

Answer (score 1):

Use a DIV instead a iframe.

```
div.innerHTML=user_text;
```

it will be automatically interpreted and displayed as html, not as text.

Answer (score 0):

I used JavaScript in one of my projects.

```
<form>
    ...
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="Preview" onclick="displayHTML(this.form)">
    ...
</form>
```

with JS:

```
function displayHTML(form)
{
    var html = form.message.value;
    win = window.open("about:blank", "Preview", "toolbar = no, status = no");
    win.document.write("" + html + "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use normal div if You want to access with php
if u can use javascript with jquery add

```
 <iframe id="iframe">

 <script>
 text = $("textarea").val();
 $("#iframe your input tag").append(text);
 </script>
```